# Save button to redirect to tab

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am attempting to redirect the user back to a specific tab upon Save. I thought I had got it with this code, but I am unable to use a Return in the public void Save()

```
public void save()
        {

        System.debug('********************************' + names);

        message = null ;       
        Boolean first = true;
        for ( SelectOption so : selectedSubs ) {
            if (first) {
                message = message ;
            }


            message = message + ', ' + so.getValue() ;

            first = false;

        }

        message=message.removeStart('null, ');
        message='['+message+']';

        System.debug('********************************' + message);
        contract.Subsidiaries_On_Contract__c=message;

        insert contract;
        contract=new Contract_Overview__c  ();
        System.debug('********************************' + contract);


      PageReference pr = new PageReference('/a23/o');
      pr.setRedirect(true);
      return pr;

        }
}
```

The tab I am attempting to get back to is the /a23/o  ;

Can anybody give some input on this ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your save method is set for as void. You will want to change it to use a PageReference return type.

```
public PageReference save()
{
      //Do Stuff 

      PageReference pr = new PageReference('/a23/o');
      pr.setRedirect(true);
      return pr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brad ! I figured it was something simple - just thought the void save would still allow me to get away with it.

Comment: It's better to dynamically retrieve the prefix of the sobject (in case of a managed package or the prefix changing).. See Andy's simple example in the link below, appending '/o' to the end of the string .  http://techman97.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/getting-prefix-of-sobject/